# Refit - How to edit mustache template

Tags: c#, mustache, refit

I'm fairly new to using Refit and C#. I'm trying to edit my `RefitStub.g.cs` page and I see a message :

```
/* ******** Hey You! *********
 *
 * This is a generated file, and gets rewritten every time you build the
 * project. If you want to edit it, you need to edit the mustache template
 * in the Refit package */
```

I'm not sure how to and where do I edit this mustache template.

I have referenced Refit through Nuget.

Answer (score 2):

Just head to `C:\Users\\{user}\\.nuget\packages\refit\\{version}\\build\\{platform}` and you should see the file `GeneratedInterfaceStubTemplate.mustache`.